# Ubuntu Server 22.10 - Failed to start session

Tags: server, session

I installed [Ubuntu Server 22.10](https://releases.ubuntu.com/22.10/ubuntu-22.10-live-server-amd64.iso) successfully.

Post installation, at the tty1 console, I installed the following packages:

```
lxqt-core lightdm gparted openvpn resolvconf libdbus-glib-1-2 bind9-dnsutils numlockx
```

I rebooted my computer and was presented with a graphical login screen. An error message appeared after I typed my login password. It is:

```
Failed to start session.
```

Thank you for your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Log into a text console by pressing `CTRL+ALT+F1`.
Install `LxQt` desktop and `sddm` display manager:
`sudo apt install lxqt sddm`

Reboot with `sudo reboot`.

If still issues, log into text console, reconfigure installed packages:
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a`

You could also nstall the Ubuntu Gnome desktop:
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it still fails to start a session. By the way, I chose LXQt for the simple reason that I wish to avoid installing Gnome desktop or any packages that have the word _gnome_ in it.

Comment: You probably should download the Lubuntu image then and start over.

Comment: Before I posted this request for help, I did download and install Lubuntu Kinetic Kudu. The installed distro contains far too many software that I don't need.